# Python requests module: Authenticate and post urlencoded information

Tags: python, python-requests

I am successfully able to urlencode my JSON information, but I cannot POST my urlencoded information because I need to authenticate when posting.

How can I do this?

My code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import pycurl
import certifi
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.post('https://website.com/update/', auth=('user', 'pass'))

uri = 'https://website.com/update/'
params = {}
data= {"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":000307,"effectiveDate":'null'}
params["data"] = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.post(uri, data=params)
print r.text
```

As you can see, I am able to post my information. But upon doing so, I need to authenticate myself before fully doing so.

I'm browsed the requests module authentication page, but none of those authentication methods worked. This works for pycurl whereas I can set my username and password, so how do I do the same with the requests module?

Comment: which authentication method you have to use ?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Basic and digest; they both don't work as it's still giving me authentication errors. I have edited my original post.

Comment: @juiceb0xk What's the error you're getting? Notice that you're mixing between `get` and `post` double check if that's correct!

Comment: requests.post and requests.get both don't work. I'm getting a InsufficientAuthenticationException error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned username and password, the authentication method is most likely **HTTP Basic Authentication** which can be easily done with `requests` like this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.post('https://website.com/update/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my original post. I have tried both basic and digest authentication methods. Both don't work as it still gives me an authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has some sort of frontend you can already access with a browser, try developer tools on Chrome to see how the authentication is done (method, parameters) and try to replicate that.

Afterwards you can most likely use the requests session object. This will help you authenticate only once and not for every request you make.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.4/user/advanced/#session-objects

Open a new session:

`s = requests.Session()`

Do your auth using the session; this is just an example, you could do your auth however your app supports(a post request for example)

`s.auth = ('user', 'pass')`

If you have any session settings (cookies, headers, etc) you have to add them to your session.

`s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})`